# Git Bash only working when Trend Micro is disabled

Tags: git, bash, windows-10, antivirus

I recently installed Git, and Git Bash only works when my Trend Micro antivirus is totally disabled. I tried simply adding the /Git folder to Trend's exception list, but that did not work. I'm using the most recent version of git (2.10.1) on Windows 10. Is there one particular file that I should add to the exception list to take care of this? Or is there another way around this other than totally disabling Trend? My apologies, this is all quite new to me.

Comment: Just so you know Trend Micro Antivirus *is* a virus.

Comment: What are the exact symptoms? "only works when" is not really helpful.
Try adding your GIT repo to the exception list as well.

Comment: @CaringDev I'm sorry, what I said was a little inaccurate. Unless Trend is disabled, the program takes several minutes to open (if it opens at all), and it can take up to a minute to execute a command.

Comment: Ah, so @VonC advice seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in progress ([issue 35173214](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/786)) reporting slow MinTTY with rend Micro.

In your case, you need to follow "[Diagnosing performance issues](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Diagnosing-performance-issues)" in order to help diagnosing the root cause.